# logstash mutate to replace field value in output

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder

I'm trying to replace 10.100.251.98 with another IP 10.100.240.199 in my logstash config, I have tried using filter with [mutate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) function, yet, I'm unable to get the syntax wrtie

```
Sep 25 15:50:57 10.100.251.98 mail_logs: Info: New SMTP DCID 13417989 interface 172.30.75.10 address 172.30.75.12 port 25
Sep 25 15:50:57 10.100.251.98 local_mail_logs: Info: New SMTP DCID 13417989 interface 172.30.75.10 address 172.30.75.12 port 25
Sep 25 15:51:04 10.100.251.98 cli_logs: Info: PID 35559: User smaduser login from 10.217.3.22 on 172.30.75.10
Sep 25 15:51:22 10.100.251.98 cli_logs: Info: PID 35596: User smaduser login from 10.217.3.22 on 172.30.75.10
```

Here is my code:

```
input { file { path => "/data/collected" } }

filter {
    if [type] == "syslog" {
        mutate {
        replace => [ "@source_host", "10.100.251.99" ]
      }
    }
}

output {

    syslog {
        facility => "kernel"
        host => "10.100.250.199"
        port => 514
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm noticing a few things about your config. First, you don't have any log parsing. You won't be able to replace a field if it doesn't yet exist. To do this, you can use a [codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/codec-plugins.html) in your input block or a [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html). I added a simple grok filter.

You also check `if [type] == "syslog"`. You never set the type, so that check will always fail. If you want to set a type, you can do that in your input block `input { file { path => "/data/collected" type => "syslog} }`

Here is the sample config I used for testing the grok pattern and replacement of the IP.

```
input { tcp { port => 5544 } }

filter {
    grok { match => { "message" =>  "%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:log_time} %{IP:@source_host} %{DATA:log_type}: %{DATA:log_level}: %{GREEDYDATA:log_message}" } }
    mutate {
      replace => [ "@source_host", "10.100.251.199" ]
    }
}

output {
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

which outputs this:

```
{
         "message" => "Sep 25 15:50:57 10.100.251.98 mail_logs: Info: New SMTP DCID 13417989 interface 172.30.75.10 address 172.30.75.12 port 25",
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2016-09-25T14:03:20.332Z",
            "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
            "port" => 52175,
        "log_time" => "Sep 25 15:50:57",
    "@source_host" => "10.100.251.199",
        "log_type" => "mail_logs",
       "log_level" => "Info",
     "log_message" => "New SMTP DCID 13417989 interface 172.30.75.10 address 172.30.75.12 port 25"
}
```